# set single vs. double swipe for notification center

Tags: ios, notifications, center, swipe

In my app by default it takes two swipes to reveal notification center, I assume so that it wouldn't interfere in swiping games such as Fruit Ninja, etc. How could I set it so that you only need to swipe once, say, if it is paused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double swipe vs single swipe depends on the visibility of the status bar. If the status bar is visible ts a single swipe. If not, double.

Comment: +1 But what if the user doesn't want to mess with the Status Bar?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much to do about it.  Apple has not made the notification tray very adjustable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Only Apple can control this. The default setting on their end is 2 swipes. There is no way to change this setting unless you find a Private API that does so. And if you use that Private API, it will not be accepted on the App Store.